# Handling errors with the Discord API (on_error)

Tags: python, discord

I'm starting with Python and I'm currently working on a Discord bot with the API. So far so good, everything works. Now, I'm looking to host the script on a server without the console, which means I want the output to go in a file instead of in the console. I have the following currently working:

```py
import discord
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='.\output.log', filemode='w', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

xzbot = discord.Client()

# logging when the bot starts
@xzbot.event
async def on_ready():
 logging.info('Logged in as ' + xzbot.user.name + ' (' + xzbot.user.id + ')\n')
```

So this code will put any warnings and infos in output.log. With that said, it doesn't work with exceptions raised by the Discord.py such as "Permissions denied" when the bot is trying to send a message without having the permissions.

There is a built-in function in the Discord API to handle that:

```py
discord.on_error(event, *args, **kwargs)
```

So I can call this function this way:

```py
async def xzbot.on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
 pass
```

Now, I tried doing something with `event`, `*args` or `**kwargs` but I need some help here to get that in a format where I can just use `logging.warning()`. All I'm able to get is `object` as a result of a `print(*args)` and I don't know how to format that properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so this snippet of code will log, and also send a message to the channel where the error was caused.

You can remove the `await xzbot.send_message` if you wouldn't like it to send a message.

```
import traceback
@xzbot.event
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    message = args[0] #Gets the message object
    logging.warning(traceback.format_exc()) #logs the error
    await xzbot.send_message(message.channel, "You caused an error!") #send the message to the channel
```

traceback.format_exc() formats the last error, so it will look like a normal error that is printed to the console.

[Here's info on the traceback module.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/traceback.html)